# Laravel email client restrict style

Tags: php, html, laravel, email

I made a laravel email client that displays emails as conversations, but the problem is how to restrict styles only for emails? Once I open an email with  tags the whole email client's style changes. For example  tags underlines and changes color. If I remove style or put !important to main css file then emails loose their original appearance.Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use an iframe for rendering the email content. This way any styles/tags within the email content are restricted to the iframe only and the email is rendered as intended.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it too, but system is ajax based and would require a lot of rewriting.